# Oracle getTime() keep milliseconds

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, date, jdbc

We have a Spring + Hibernate Java 7 web-application. We currently use `.hbm.xml` Hibernate files (instead of the more common known annotations) as mapping between the Java entities and database tables.

One of our Java entity classes has a `java.util.Date` with millisecond precision:

```
public class SomeEntity extends AbstractEntity{
   ...

   private java.util.Date someDate; // with ms precision

   ...
}
```

In our `.hbm.xml` file we have the following for this date:

```
...
<hibernate-mapping>
  <class name="com.namespace.Entity" table="entity" batch-size="10">
     ...
     <property name="SomeDate" column="somedate" type="com.namespace.CustomDateType" />
     ...
```

Which is linked to a database table with the following row:

```
SOMEDATE  TIMESTAMP(2)  NULLABLE=Yes
```

Our `CustomDateType` class:

```
package com.namespace.type;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Timestamp;
import java.sql.Types;
import java.util.Date;

import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

public class CustomDateType implements UserType {

  private static final int[] SQL_TYPES = { Types.TIMESTAMP };

  @Override
  public Object assemble(final Serializable serializable, final Object o) {
    return deepCopy(serializable);
  }

  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(final Object value) {
    return value;
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(final Object o) {
    return (Serializable) deepCopy(o);
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(final Object x, final Object y) {
    if (x == y) {
      return true;
    } else if ((x == null) || (y == null)) {
      return false;
    }
    return x.equals(y);
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(final Object o) {
    return ((CustomDateType) o).hashCode();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet resultSet, final String[] names, final Object owner) throws SQLException {
    Date result = null;
    final Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(names[0]); // This is where the problem is
    if (!resultSet.wasNull()) {
      result = new Date(timestamp.getTime());
    }
    return result;
  }

  @Override
  public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement statement, final Object value, final int index) throws SQLException {
    final Date dateToSet = (Date) value;
    statement.setTimestamp(index, dateToSet == null ? null : new Timestamp(dateToSet.getTime()));
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(final Object o, final Object o1, final Object o2) {
    return o;
  }

  @Override
  public Class<Date> returnedClass() {
    return Date.class;
  }

  @Override
  public int[] sqlTypes() {
    return SQL_TYPES;
  }
}
```

When debugging `someDate` does indeed have milliseconds in the Java class. But, in the `CustomDateType#nullSafeGet` method the resulting `TimeStamp` doesn't have any milliseconds anymore.

The `resultSet` parameter is the `oracle.jdbc.driver.ForwardOnlyResultSet`, which continues into `oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement`, which continues into the class & method where the core of the problem is: `oracle.jdbc.driver.DateTimeCommonAccessor#getTime(int, Calendar)`

In this method the `milliseconds` are stripped and you are left with `second`-precision.

Is there any way to keep the milliseconds in this situation? How to save millisecond precision when going from `java.util.Date` to database `TIMESTAMP`-typed column?

NOTE: The milliseconds are already gone before going into the database table. If I put a breakpoint at `final Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimestamp(names[0]);` and step over, the resulting `timestamp` will have no milliseconds anymore.

---

EDIT: The contents of the `hava.util.Date` object and `java.sql.Timestamp` objects during debugging:

[image]
[image]

The `fraction` and `millis` are both removed and put to `0`..

Comment: you should be using `java.sql.Timestamp` for timestamp columns. Not `java.util.Date`

Comment: Why are you first getting a `java.sqlTimestamp` and then getting a `java.sql.Time`. Note that `java.sql.Time` has a precision in seconds, not milliseconds (note that the documentation is not entirely clear, you need to read between the lines for this limitation), if you want subsecond precision, you must use a `java.sql.Timestamp`.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Hmm ok, I indeed understand that `Time` and `Timestamp` have different precision, and this Oracle JDBC `getTime` call is the root of the problem. But if I strictly look at our own code I see `Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimeStamp(names[0]);`. After that things are being called by `oracle.jdbc`, and for some reason it ends up at `DateTimeCommonAccessor#getTime(...)` instead of `getTimestamp(...)`. I'll investigate where it transitions from the original getTimestamp to getTime, but do you perhaps have an idea where this might happen, and more importantly: why / how?

Comment: Sorry, I was looking cross-eyed; I thought your code was calling `resultSet.getTime`, but it doesn't. What is the type of the column, if it is `DATE`, then Oracle doesn't have fractional seconds, but at max second precision. You need a `TIMESTAMP` column for fractional seconds (and then make sure it isn't a `TIMESTAMP(0)`, the default is `TIMESTAMP(6)` btw. Also check the version of your database driver, if it is a really old one, it might just try to handle it as `DATE` instead

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Ah, forgot to mention it in the question. But it is indeed a `TIMESTAMP`. A `TIMESTAMP(2)` to be exact. The issue however is before it goes into the database. When I place a debug breakpoint on the line after `Timestamp timestamp = resultSet.getTimeStamp(name[0]);` and check this timestamp, the milliseconds are gone.

Comment: Exactly how do you check the timestamp. A `java.sql.Timestamp` stores second precision in the `java.util.Date` `fastTime` field (instead of milliseconds for a normal `java.util.Date`), and it has a separate `nanos` field for sub-second precision. When you call `java.sql.Timestamp.getTime()` it recombines these two into a millisecond precision value.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I must admit your previous comment sounded very plausible, but unfortunately `timestamp.getTime()` also lacks the ms. I've added a screenshot of both the Date and Timestamp during debugging to the question.

Comment: Your screenshot shows a time of 00:00:00.001 (which I assume is what you stored), however since you have a `TIMESTAMP(2)`, then you actually store 00:00:00.00 (only subsecond precision of 2), which is also what you retrieve. You might want to check with - for example - 00:00:00.12, or use a `TIMESTAMP(3)` or even higher precision.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I will update my DB-column to `TIMESTAMP(6)` on my local database, but I think you just hit the nail on the head! Apparently the Date we receive has a ms precision of 17 points, but the database only stores up to 16 at the moment. I'm currently working on a small other issue, but I'll change it in a moment and let you know if that fixes the problem. It seems VERY likely, though.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Thank you very much, that did the trick! If you could make an answer I will accept it as the correct one. After changing the column to `TIMESTAMP(6)` it works. Just like you said, the `java.sql.Timestamp` now contains (`-400208400000 (1957-04-27T00:00:00.000+0100)` and `nanos = 1000000`). And now it also shows `27-04-57 00:00:00,001000000` in the database column after saving. And thanks to your comments above I now also have a better understanding on how `Timestamp` works in general.

Comment: Glad to have been of help, I have written an answer with a summary of my comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `java.sql.Timestamp` stores second precision in the `java.util.Date` `fastTime` field (instead of milliseconds for a normal `java.util.Date`), and it has a separate `nanos` field for sub-second precision. When you call `java.sql.Timestamp.getTime()` it recombines these two into a millisecond precision value.

As you have declared your field as `TIMESTAMP(2)`, it means you only have 2 decimals of sub-second precision. If you try to store `00:00:00.001`, what actually gets stored is `00:00:00:00`, and that is also what you retrieve again. In other words, you need to increase precision by declaring the field as `TIMESTAMP(3)` (or even higher, up to 9 is supported), or you need to live with the reduced precision of two decimals.

Note that if you use an higher than millisecond precision (so more than 3 decimals), you can only get that full precision using `java.sql.Timestamp.getNanos()`, which contains the full sub-second precision (the `nanos` are only the sub second fraction and should always be less than 1 second), or by converting the `Timestamp` to a `java.time.LocalDateTime`.